# Disable dragging when hovering on a node in Reactflow

Tags: react-flow

I don't want to allow users drag the nodes, and that is possible with `draggable: false` option, or the prop that disables it for all the nodes. But when i go to a node click and drag a node the node doesn't drag but the background does and it looks like that the node is being dragged, is there any option to disable dragging when the user hovers on a node, or any other option that fixes this?